# Intuition behind transformations of functions (horizontal shifting)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, intuition, transformation

I know $f(x-c)$ is the graph of $f(x)$ shifted to the right $c$ units, but is there any sort of intuitive way of looking at this?

Comment: What kind of intuition? For example, if you think of $x$ as time, things happen $c$ units of time later for $f(x-c)$ than they do for the original $f(x)$, but I don't know if that's the kind of thinking you're looking for.

Comment: Easiest thing to do is to just look at it's inverse.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of $x$ as units of time $t$ and and $f(t)$ as a function telling you what happens to you at time $t$ (for example at $t=3$, $f(3)$ translates into you eating breakfast), the transformation $f(t-c)$ basically means that whatever used to happen to you at time $t$ now happens earlier, at $t-c$ (for example, if $c=1$, you will be eating breakfast at $t=2$).

Is this the type of intuition you were looking for?

Comment: "you will be eating breakfast at $t=2$": Oughtn't this be $t - c = 3 - 1 = 2$?